# binarize a sparse matrix in python in a different way

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, sparse-matrix

Assume I have a matrix like:

```
4 0 3 5
0 2 6 0
7 0 1 0
```

I want it binarized as:

```
0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0
```

That is set threshold equal to 2, any element greater than the threshold is set to 0, any element less or equal than the threshold(except 0) is set to 1.

Can we do this on python's csr_matrix or any other sparse matrix?

I know scikit-learn offer Binarizer to replace values below or equal to the threshold by 0, above it by 1.

Comment: Did you try anything to solve this?

Comment: I am looking for a generic way to do this. Actually I know how to do this row by row. But I cannot come up with more efficient way right now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When dealing with a sparse matrix, `s`, avoid inequalities that include zero since a sparse matrix (if you're using it appropriately) should have a great many zeros and forming an array of all the locations which are zero would be huge. So avoid `s <= 2` for example. Use inequalities that select away from zero instead.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse

s = sparse.csr_matrix(np.array([[4, 0, 3, 5],
         [0, 2, 6, 0],
         [7, 0, 1, 0]]))

print(s)
# <3x4 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
#   with 7 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

s[s > 2] = 0
s[s != 0] = 1

print(s.todense())
```

yields

```
matrix([[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0]])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import scipy.sparse
>>> mat = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(np.array([[4, 0, 3, 5],
         [0, 2, 6, 0],
         [7, 0, 1, 0]])).todense()
>>> np.where(np.logical_and(mat <= 2, mat !=0), 1, 0)
matrix([[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be very efficient way to do this but it can be achieved using simple `function` and `list` operations as below

```
def binarized(matrix, threshold):
    for row in matrix:
        for each in range(len(matrix)+1):
            if row[each] > threshold:
                row[each] = 0
            elif row[each] != 0:
                row[each] = 1
    return matrix


matrix = [[4, 0, 3, 5],
          [0, 2, 6, 0],
          [7, 0, 1, 0]]

print binarized(matrix, 2)
```

**Yeilds** :

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 0]]
```

Comment: This is very straightforward solution, I just wonder is there any existed function or model can do this, something like scikit-learn's Binarizer. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: So you are expecting a pre existing module or library for this solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np                                                                                            

x = np.array([[4, 0, 3, 5],                                                                                   
              [0, 2, 6, 0],                                                                                   
              [7, 0, 1, 0]])                                                                                  

threshold = 2                                                                                                  
x[x<=0]=threshold+1                                                                                            
x[x<=threshold]=1                                                                                              
x[x>threshold]=0                                                                                               
print x
```

**output:**

```
[[0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0]]
```